# What are tools or library to visualize real-estate price on map?

Tags: data-visualization

What are appropriate tool or library to plot real-estate price on map. Let's say I have list of real-estate listings that consist of the price and coordinate (latitude and longitude).

**UPDATED**

I understand this can be very controversial. So here's some background. I have millions of real-estate data that consist of price and coordinate. And I have a proficiency in Java and Python programming. But I don't really have a background on data visualization.

Basically I want to visualize the data to the users so that they can understand the distribution of the price in their neighborhood.

It would be nice if there is a library (for web, i.e. HTML5/CSS/Javascript) to do visualization.

Comment: This seems to be a software-only question, so could be better asked on Stack Overflow.  But, you can do this (many ways) in R ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen No, this is not a good question for Stack Overflow because it is asking for a tool or library. We don't accept this type of question on SO.

Comment: This question seems to invite a list of "download this software" answers.  In order to remain focused, on-topic, and objective, please modify the question. Consider, for instance, explaining the purpose of the visualization; or asking for appropriate ways to present such information; or providing some kind of contextual information that will enable people to arrive at (and evaluate) objectively good answers.

Answer (score 2):

[Google fusion tables](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2571232): See e.g. the [demo data](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1-941Px73b_XWWn3pmPHKp6WhbbSVNiEmKMadwe0#map:id=3) they have, and their [example gallery](https://sites.google.com/site/fusiontablestalks/stories).

[Excel 2013 power map addin](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/get-started-with-power-map-HA104091224.aspx), or [power view addin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sc4aXZOegEI) (which is free to download for certain versions of Excel--e.g., standalone).

Both of the above will work with a comma separated text file (CSV).

Answer (score 0):

Download [this free trial of JMP](http://www.jmp.com/software/try-jmp.shtml?ref=nav), it has an integrated map graph that you can turn into a heat map. it even has built in maps already!